# How to get current window pageYOffset in styled component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Im struggling with translate animation which depends on scrollYOffset of a window.

I've got something like this :

```
const StyledHeading = styled.h1`
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontSize.l};
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.firaSans};
  margin: 0;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(${({ offset }) => (offset > 100 ? '-50px' : '0px')});
`;

export default function Navbar() {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(window.pageYOffset);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      setOffset(window.pageYOffset);
    });
  });

  return (
    <StyledHeader >
      <StyledWrapper>
        <StyledHeading offset={offset}>
          Bookphiles <i className="fas fa-book-open" />
        </StyledHeading>
        <nav>
          <NavLinks  />
        </nav>
      </StyledWrapper>
    </StyledHeader>
  );
}
```

But its seems to be done in very inefficient way, because every scroll causes DOM rerender. Can this be done in some better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, if you want to avoid choppy animation, you should rely on refs DOM management instead of React render():

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createRef } from 'react';

export default function Navbar() {
  const ref = createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  });

  handleScroll = (e) => {
      const offset = window.pageYOffset;
      ref.current.style.transform = `translateX(${({ offset }) => (offset > 100 ? '-50px' : '0px')})`;
  }

  return (
    //...code
        <StyledHeading ref={ref}>
          Bookphiles <i className="fas fa-book-open" />
        </StyledHeading>
    //..code
  );
}
```

Notice that there could be some typo in my code but the concept is to not involve re-rendering in scroll management.
**Remember to remove the listener before unmounting your component.**

Comment: Should i access ref in my styled component or it just style it automaticly?

Comment: Just in style, if you pass it to your Styled you'll need a re-render to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a throttle or debounce function from lodash to limit the number of times your event handler function is executed. This way the event handler will only be executed at most every 200 milliseconds:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(() => {
  setOffset(window.pageYOffset);
}, 200));
```

This is a good article that explains this idea in more detail and provides more examples: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/